# Arrows in UML diagrams

Tags: java, uml

I am dealing with UML diagrams and I am specifically confused about certain types of arrows between Java Class and Java Interface. I was trying to find the answer but I didnt find the answer which would made me my problem clear.

This picture below and arrows that are between are confusing me, what are those arrows saying and how it related to my code?

[image]

Comment: You should ask the person who drew this diagram. My advice, if you want to know what the code does, would be to read the code. Diagrams are usually out of date, and often less clear than the code they're supposed to describe.

Comment: Yes, ask the author. The names are supposed to be roles (properties on the other side). But they are positioned so badly that you can't even read them, and even less tell where they belong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagram is saying that the Team class has a private attribute named startingEleven(its difficult to read..)  and a protected named registeredPlayes.  Both of type SimpleFootBallPlayerCollection.  And in the SimpleFootBallPlayerCollection interface there is a class that implements it, but we can only see the end of the arrow.

- From Team to SimpleFootBallPlayerCollection: Its a association, where Team has a SimpleFootBallPlayerCollection
- From Unknow class to SimpleFootBallPlayerCollection: Its a realization, where Unknow class implements SimpleFootBallPlayerCollection

Check this [link](http://idiotechie.com/uml2-class-diagram-in-java/)!  It is explaning the uml arrows and properties implementing they in Java!